# Strange behaviour with locale decimal point and type casting

Tags: php

Locale is set to `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')`
In Russia, decimal point is `,`.

I'm getting string input (for example, `11,25`).
When I'm typecasting it to double `$double = (double)$double;` I'm loosing precision.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');

$input = '11,25';
var_dump((double)$input); //11

$linfo = localeconv();
$input = '11'.$linfo['decimal_point'].'25';
var_dump((double)$input); //11

$input = '11.25';
var_dump((double)$input); //11,25
```

So, as I can see locale effects only view.
Does it mean that I should always `str_replace(array(',','.'), '.', $input)` before operating decimal values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `setlocale` have failed. Try replacing `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');` with

```
if (false !== setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB')) {
    echo "Locale set";
}
else{
    echo "Locale set failed";
}
```

The code you have posted gives me `Locale set failed` (win7x86, PHP 5.2.12, system locale is en_US).

**UPDATED**

On Win it's `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Russian_Russia.1251')` but the result of conversions is just like you described.

The answer can be found in [Using setlocale() doesn't affect PHPs number conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809866/using-setlocale-doesnt-affect-phps-number-conversions). In short, typecasting is not affected by locale settings (see [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)) You'll have to replace locale-based decimal separators with dots first. I think

```
str_replace($linfo['decimal_point'], '.', $input)
```

would be more appropriate, flexible and robust (though I don't aware of culture that uses decimal separator other than comma and dot :) ).

Answer (score -2):

In PHP decimal point is `.`. It's not depending on locale.